# Activiti error:using JavaScript in .bpmn20.xml

Tags: javascript, activiti, bpmn, business-process-management

I tried to use JS like that in Activiti process:

```
<process id="test_model" isExecutable="true">
        <startEvent id="414-013"></startEvent>
        <scriptTask id="javascriptScript" name="jsTask" scriptFormat="JavaScript" activiti:autoStoreVariables="false">
            <script><![CDATA[
                var my = "Bla bla bla";
                console.log(my);
            ]]></script>
        </scriptTask>
        <endEvent id="0DC2EF"></endEvent>
    </process>
```

This xml uploaded perfect, but when I try Start Process, I have error:

```
Reference Error:"console" is not defined at line 3
```

Also I tried create new Form in js:

```
var form = new FormData();
```

And again I have the same error.

What I`m doing wrong? In what this error?

Thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.activiti.org/userguide/index.html#bpmnScriptTask

> By default JavaScript is included in every JDK and as such doesn’t
>   need any additional jars.

Default JavaScript engine is [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino) (JDK6, JDK7) or [Nashorn](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nashorn/) (JDK8+) depending on JDK version. These engines do not support browser APIs and therefore don't provide browser specific objects like `console`. The main purposue of the bundled engines is scripting java, see [Java Scripting Programmer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/)

---

For output use `print` function

```
 var my = "Bla bla bla";
 print(my);
```